# Logic for form validation before insert into database

Tags: php, forms, validation

I would like to write a logic for data validation before insert into database.  If the data not valid, then it will prompt user errors, but then I facing problem which not the logic that I wish:
(1) Message "Data successfully inserted!" shown even the error checking message was prompt.
(2) Message "Data successfully inserted!" shown even no data was entered in the form then click submit.

How should I change the logic to the one that I wish to have?

```
<?php
// Initialize variables to null.
$comp_nameError ="";
$compLicenseeNameError ="";

if(isset($_POST['comp_name']))  {$comp_name= $_POST['comp_name'];}
if(isset($_POST['comp_licensee_name'])) {$comp_licensee_name= $_POST['comp_licensee_name'];}

//On submitting form below function will execute
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }           

    //-------------------------Form Validation Start---------------------//
   if (empty($_POST["comp_name"])) {
     $comp_nameError = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $comp_name = test_input($_POST["comp_name"]);
     // check name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comp_name)) {
       $comp_nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comp_licensee_name"])) {
     $compLicenseeNameError = "Company Licensee Name is required";
   } else {
     $comp_licensee_name = test_input($_POST["comp_licensee_name"]);
   }
   //-------------------------Form Validation End---------------------//


    // attempt a connection
    $host="host=xx.xx.xx.xx";
    $port="port=xxxx";
    $dbname="dbname=xxxx";
    $credentials="user=xxxxxx password=xxxxxxx";

    $dbh = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials");
    if (!$dbh) {
        die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
    }

    // execute query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_comp(comp_name, comp_licensee_name)VALUES('$comp_name', '$comp_licensee_name')";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql); 

    if (!$result) {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    }
    echo "Data successfully inserted!";

    // free memory
    pg_free_result($result); 

    // close connection
    pg_close($dbh);
}
//php code ends here 
?>


<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="maindiv">
            <div class="form_div">    
            <form method="post" action="compReg.php">                   
                <span class="error">* required field.</span>

                <br>
                <hr/>
                <br>
                Company Name:<br><input class="input" type="text" name="comp_name" value="">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $comp_nameError;?></span>
                <br>         

                Company Licensee:<br><input class="input" type="text" name="comp_licensee_name" value="">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $compLicenseeNameError;?></span>
                <br>    

                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
            </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd accumulate the errors into an array, and proceed to the insert part only if it's empty:

```
$errors = array();
if (empty($_POST["comp_name"])) {
    $errors[] = "Name is required";
} else {
    $comp_name = test_input($_POST["comp_name"]);
    // check name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comp_name)) {
        $errors[] = "Only letters and white space allowed in the computer name"; 
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["comp_licensee_name"])) {
    $errors[] = "Company Licensee Name is required";
} else {
    $comp_licensee_name = test_input($_POST["comp_licensee_name"]);
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    echo "The following errors occurred:<br/>" . implode('<br/>', $errors);
    exit();
}

// If we didn't exit, continue to the insertion code
```

Comment: we not suppose to echo array, so what I'm gonna do with this? 
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $validationError[];?></span>

Comment: @JaydenSpancer I don't understand the question - I'm not echoing an array, I'm imploding it to a string.

Comment: It prompt me message as below: 
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C: xxxxx

which detect from this line lines  
<br>
    Company Name:<br><input class="input" type="text" name="comp_name" value="">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $validationError;?></span>
    <br>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    // Initialize variables to null.
   $comp_nameError ="";
   $compLicenseeNameError ="";

    if(isset($_POST['comp_name']))  {$comp_name= $_POST['comp_name'];}
       if(isset($_POST['comp_licensee_name'])) {
             $comp_licensee_name= $_POST['comp_licensee_name'];}

           //On submitting form below function will execute
             if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                // check boolean variable value 
                $is_valid = 1;

                function test_input($data) {
                    $data = trim($data);
                    $data = stripslashes($data);
                    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                      return $data;
                 }           

     //-------------------------Form Validation Start---------------------//
      if (empty($_POST["comp_name"])) {
          $comp_nameError = "Name is required";
          } else {
            $comp_name = test_input($_POST["comp_name"]);
          // check name only contains letters and whitespace
           if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comp_name)) {
             $validation_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
               $is_valid = 0;
           }
     }

        if (empty($_POST["comp_licensee_name"])) {
           $validation_error = "Company Licensee Name is required";
           $is_valid =0;
          } else {
             $comp_licensee_name = test_input($_POST["comp_licensee_name"]);
            }
          //-------------------------Form Validation End---------------------//


        // attempt a connection
  if($is_valid == 1 ){
    $host="host=xx.xx.xx.xx";
    $port="port=xxxx";
    $dbname="dbname=xxxx";
    $credentials="user=xxxxxx password=xxxxxxx";

    $dbh = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials");
    if (!$dbh) {
        die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
    }

    // execute query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_comp(comp_name, comp_licensee_name)VALUES('$comp_name', '$comp_licensee_name')";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql); 

    if (!$result) {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    }
    echo "Data successfully inserted!";

    // free memory
    pg_free_result($result); 

    // close connection
    pg_close($dbh);
} else {
     echo $validation_error; 
     die;
}
 }
 //php code ends here 
?>
```